# Only double click de-selects collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, uicollectionview

So here are functions that are making the problem:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = calendarView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CalendarCell else { return }

    if cell.isSelectable! {
        if selectedDates.filter({ $0.isDateSameDay(cell.currentDate)
        }).count == 0 {
            selectedDates.append(cell.currentDate)
            cell.selectCell(#colorLiteral(red: 0.721568644, green: 0.8862745166, blue: 0.5921568871, alpha: 1))
            selectTodayCell(cell: cell)
        } else {
            deselectCell(cell:cell)
            setTodayCellColor(cell: cell)
            print(selectedDates)
        }
    }
}

private func deselectCell(cell: CalendarCell) {
    selectedDates = selectedDates.filter() {
        return  !($0.isDateSameDay(cell.currentDate))
    }
    if cell.currentDate.isSaturday() || cell.currentDate.isSunday() {
        cell.deselectCell(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
    }
    else {
        cell.deselectCell(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
    }
}
```

Very simple extension of date :

```
func isDateSameDay(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
    return (self.day() == date.day()) && (self.month() == date.month() && (self.year() == date.year()))
}
```

So the problem is de-selection already selected cell. You need to press only once to make cell selected, and twice to deSelect it.
I am trying to make it one for selection, and one for de-selection. 
Functions inside cell classes, are basically just changing label textColor, and background color, so there isn't any sense to post them.
I don't have any Gesture Recognizers in whole project, and I'm wondering if filter function, that is quite demanding for device can make this strange bug? Or deselectCell should be called in async block?

Comment: I'm not completely clear on the problem you are describing.  Are you saying you expect the cell to show selected when the user taps it and then automatically switch to deselected without another tap?

Comment: No. U Are taping once on cell and it is changing color, but you need to tap twice on selected cell to de-select it. The problem is that double tap. I want to make it tap once to select, and tap one more time on selected cell to de-select it

Comment: Put break point on two methods and check if the tap on selected cell is calling the deselect method.

Comment: Deselect method is called after two taps. There is only one object in array.